# How to install Panda3D game engine?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, games, engine

I'd like to get started with the Panda3D game engine, but I can't find any tutorials on setting it up on Linux.

How can I can set up the engine on Ubuntu 14.04? Or could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only build for Trusty is the current unstable build. That might be fine or you could [build the development copy from source](https://github.com/panda3d/panda3d/blob/master/README.md). This is all extremely documented. Here's how I'd install from the unstable packages:

1. Download [the SDK deb installers](https://www.panda3d.org/download.php?platform=ubuntu&version=1.9.0&sdk) and install.
2. Optionally do the same for the samples (same link)
3. Follow [the tutorial](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Installing_Panda3D_in_Linux) to test the samples.
4. Continue following [the manual](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Main_Page) to learn more about it.

Comment: If I used the unstable build, could I install it simply with `sudo apt-get install panda3d`?

Comment: No, Apt only works for things in a repository and as far as I know, panda3d isn't in one. That's why I suggested downloading the debs manually.